# Как сделать анимацию вокруг круга

Tags: javascript, css, анимация

Подскажите как сделать что-то подобное в css и js. Как сделать такую тень. Хочу чтобы эта "тень" двигалась. Спасибо[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Каким образом двигалась?

Comment: Хочу, чтобы тень пульсировала.

Comment: @Olga, пульсацию можно сделать через анимацию tranform scale, по крайней мере, если она должна быть для всей тени, а не частями. А саму тень - ничего лучше svg или картинки тут не выйдет, скорее всего.

Comment: Спасибо, буду пробовать.

Answer (score 0):

можно и без участия js сделать, на одном css.
Берем нужное изображение (в вашем случае картинку "тени") и прописываем для него в css анимацию вращения (если вам нужно именно вращать):

```css
.circle {
  width: 200px;
  animation: circle-rotation 60s infinite linear;
}
@keyframes circle-rotation {
  100% { transform: rotate(360deg); } 
}
```

```html
<img class="circle" src="https://svgx.ru/svg/34139.svg" alt="">
```

прочитать о свойствах подробнее можно тут: [анимация](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Animations/Using_CSS_animations) и [трансформация](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Transforms/Using_CSS_transforms)

Comment: Спасибо. Как можно сделать пульсацию? Не хотела добавлять картинку. Хочу сделать только пульсирующий контур, который будет пустой внутри.

Comment: вместо transform: rotate(360deg) используйте transform: scale(1.1, 1.1) - в скобках указаны величины, на которые ваше изображение будет увеличиваться, можете изменить на свои. И продолжительность цикла можно уменьшить до 2s

Comment: Спасибо Вам за помощь.

Comment: @TaniaLinn так будет менять только в одну сторону, в итоге плавной анимации не видать.

Comment: @ΝNL993 для плавной анимации можно настроить несколько шагов внутри keyframes, указывая изменения хоть для каждого 1%: "@keyframes circle-rotation {30% { transform: scale(0.9, 0.9); }  50% { transform: scale(1, 1); } 70% { transform: scale(1.1, 1.1); } 100% { transform: scale(1, 1); }}"

Comment: @TaniaLinn это я и так знал, вы это **сразу** должны были сказать пользователю *Olga*, т.к. обязательно для подробного объяснения.